# Ubuntu, nautilus, terminal, ten thousand files

Tags: 22.04, nautilus, gnome-terminal, freeze

I downloaded and extracted an archive which contains about ten thousand files. Then I cd into that directory. As soon as I did this, Nautilus began to have problems displaying such a large number of files. My next big mistake was to press CTRL+A to select all the files. After that, it completely stopped responding. I closed the window but the following problems occurred:

1. When I open the terminal and type something for the first time the text/command is displayed fast and smoothly until I either press tab or hit enter. Once I hit them, and start typing the command "cat", the first two "ca" letters are displayed fast and smoothly, while the last "t" character is delayed for half of a second. When I press "tab" I also see suggestions with a delay. When I close and re-open the terminal the first command again runs smoothly.
2. Also when I run commands (press enter) in the terminal the kernel executes them with a delay. Even very simple commands like "cd" can be delayed for a second.
3. When I select and right-click inside the terminal it takes half a second to render the context menu (I see those frames).
4. Nautilus rendering problems became visible. When I press CTRL+A in any directory (even if it contains 5-10 files) I can observe how slowly it highlights the whole row i.e. the first part of the row (File name) is highlighted, then Size, then Modified.

What I did:

1. Removed all the cache from the home directory.
2. Disabled tracker3 and cleared their database.
3. Updated Nvidia drivers to the latest stable, tested version.
4. Disabled bash completion.

Resource usage:
The CPU, memory, and disk IO are in a normal state except `gnome-shell` which has a 1.3 GB disk write total.

Error log:
Nothing special is noticeable when I run `journalctl -f`

Other programs:
Other programs (IDE, browsers, apps) run smoothly.

Neofetch:

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               ubuntu@ubuntu-B450M-DS3H 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ---------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: B450M DS3H 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.5.0-26-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 1 hour, 4 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2406 (dpkg), 34 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 42.9 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X (16) @ 3.600G 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 4982MiB / 32002MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Comment: 1,2,3,4: why?  I would just reboot and delete the directory from command line :P

Comment: What is the output of `free`, is there some disk swapping on the way? I'm using thunar, not nautilus, which is not impressed by that amount of files, if I view them in list mode (2-3 s to complete the list, mark all: instantly). However, if I switch to `symbol/icon view` (my personal translation), which displays one bigger icon per file, for images a thumbnail of the content, the machine is nearly going to an halt (despite all the files being empty, 99.000 files).

Comment: @Rinzwind I immediately deleted this folder through the terminal. 1-2-3-4 are the problems I encountered after closing the nautilus graphical interface.

Comment: @userunknown Used/free is 3.6GB/26GB. Swap is 0.

Comment: Deleting the directory was, imho, a panic reaction without good chances of being helpful. If you're driving downhill with your car and it starts slingering, you wouldn't turn off the motor - well, bad example, I confess. The machine is already in an unhealthy state, maybe it has already opened 50k of 8k files and this might help, but maybe it has now to recover from 50k files missing files, and as long as the files are open, they only get marked deleted for further access - any open file will still be available. You can check this out by playing a long podcast and delete it, while playing.

Comment: @userunknown I agree. This was not a timely decision.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by re-installing nautilus
`sudo apt purge nautilus && sudo apt install nautilus`

Comment: I doubt it. I guess if you repeat the steps from above, you might encounter the same problem. Are you willing to install nautilus on a regular basis? Of course, disabling file preview/thumbnails (if there is such an option) is only a workaround (if my suspicion is true - it might be false and some other bottleneck at work). However, you should have tested, whether logoff/logon or rebooting as minor invasive actions would have solved the acute problem. Of course - depending on your needs, reinstalling might be the minor action.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure that might encounter the same problem if I repeat the steps above, however, most of the time I work in the terminal, so it needs to be fast and responsive.